# Call Alexa SKill over API request

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Is possible to call a skill from Alexa using an API?
When I search about this i find things about use API inside skill code from developer.amazon.com, but in this case we use API in skill. Not the API calling this skill from a request

Is possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: Not today

Why? Because using Alexa requires an account and no API is available to login as a user on Alexa. Maybe one day, that would be helpful.